# Insert span into div after comma using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to able to inject a span after a comma using jQuery. I have a number of divs that look like this:

```
    <div class="title">Some text, with a comma.</div>
    <div class="title">Some text, with a comma.</div>
    <div class="title">Some text, with a comma.</div>
    <div class="title">Some text, with a comma.</div>
    <div class="title">Some text, with a comma.</div>
    <div class="title">Some text, with a comma.</div>
```

I want to make them all look like this:

```
<div class="title">Some text,<span class="something"> with a comma.</span></div>
```

Is there a way to append text or html after the comma and only targeting the class of title?

Comment: What have you tried?  Please post the code you have created in attempting to solve the problem.

Comment: What if there's more than one comma? Should the new element be duplicated for each instance, or be inserted at the first, last or other instance? Also, strictly speaking, the answer to your question is 'yes.' The longer answer is that it depends, on precisely what you want, and what constraints, and requirements, you might have.

Comment: Okay guys .... give me a couple of minutes before downvoting this into oblivion.

Comment: I've neither down-voted, nor voted to close, but had you taken a couple of minutes before posting the question you'd probably not have so many adverse  votes as you currently have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.title').html(function(i, v){
    var html = v.split(',');
    return html[0] + ',' + '<span class="something">' + html[1] + '</span>'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/udjCs/2/

Comment: If you're going to pass a function to `.html()`, then you might as well use the second parameter to the callback instead of doing `$(this).html()`. http://jsfiddle.net/udjCs/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('div.title').each(function(){
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(',', ', <span class="something">') );
});
```

But I still think you need to explain what you need better.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is probably to slice the HTML string into parts, and then parse that:

```
$(".title").html(function (index, html) {
    var commaIndex = html.indexOf(",");
    var beginningHtml = html.substring(0, commaIndex + 1);
    var endingHtml = html.substring(commaIndex + 1);
    return beginningHtml + "<span class=\"something\">" + endingHtml + "<\/span>";
});
```

Here's [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QDXRU/2/) for my code.